# Supervision tree conflict in an umbrella app

Tags: elixir, umbrella

### Background

I have an umbrella app that has many smaller apps inside. One of this apps, called `A`, needs to be able to spin and supervise another app, called `B`.

`B`, being an app in its own right, exposes a public API and has a GenServer, responsible for receiving requests that it then redirects to the logic modules and such.

### Issue

So, I have two requirements:

1. I must be able to launch `B` independently and have it work as a normal standalone app.
2. `A` must be able to have `B` in its children and restart/manage it, should such a need arise.

The problem I have here, is that with my code I can either achieve 1 or 2, but not both.

### Code

So, the following is the important code for app `B`:

**application.ex**

```
defmodule B.Application do
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  alias B.Server
  alias Plug.Cowboy

  @test_port 8082

  @spec start(any, nil | maybe_improper_list | map) :: {:error, any} | {:ok, pid}
  def start(_type, args) do
    # B.Server is a module containing GenServer logic and callbacks
    children = children([Server])

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: B.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

end
```

**server.ex** (simplified)

```
defmodule B.Server do
  use GenServer

  alias B.HTTPClient

  #############
  # Callbacks #
  #############

  @spec start_link(any) :: :ignore | {:error, any} | {:ok, pid}
  def start_link(_args), do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, name: __MODULE__)

  @impl GenServer
  @spec init(nil) :: {:ok, %{}}
  def init(nil), do: {:ok, %{}}

  @impl GenServer
  def handle_call({:place_order, order}, _from, _state), do:
    {:reply, HTTPClient.place_order(order), %{}}

  @impl GenServer
  def handle_call({:delete_order, order_id}, _from, _state), do:
    {:reply, HTTPClient.delete_order(order_id), %{}}

  @impl GenServer
  def handle_call({:get_all_orders, item_name}, _from, _state), do:
    {:reply, HTTPClient.get_all_orders(item_name), %{}}

  ##############
  # Public API #
  ##############

  def get_all_orders(item_name), do:
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:get_all_orders, item_name})

  def place_order(order), do:
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:place_order, order})

  def delete_order(order_id), do:
    GenServer.call(__MODULE__, {:delete_order, order_id})

end
```

And here is the entrypoint of `B`

**b.ex**

```
defmodule B do
  @moduledoc """
  Port for http client.
  """

  alias B.Server

  defdelegate place_order(order), to: Server

  defdelegate delete_order(order_id), to: Server

  defdelegate get_all_orders(item_name), to: Server

  @doc false
  defdelegate child_spec(args), to: Server
end
```

`b.ex` is basically a facade for the Server, with some extra context information such as specs, type definitions, etc (omitted here for the sake of brevity).

### How does `A` manage the lifecycle?

It is my understanding that supervision trees are specified in the `application.ex` file of apps. So, from my understanding, I have created this application file for `A`:

```
defmodule A.Application do
  @moduledoc false

  use Application

  alias B

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [B]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: A.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

end
```

Which should work, except it doesn't.

When inside `A`'s folder, if I run `iex -S mix`, instead of having a nice launch I get the following error:

```
** (Mix) Could not start application a: A.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: B.Server
    ** (EXIT) already started: #PID<0.329.0>
```

My current understanding of the issue is that `A`'s application.ex file is conflicting with `B`'s application file.

### Questions

1. How do I fix this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the requirement correctly, `A` wants to ultimately stop `B` application and respawn `B` process supervised,

[`Application.stop/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html#stop/1) is doing exactly this.

```rb
defmodule A.Application do
  ...
  def start(_type, _args) do
    Application.stop(:b) # ⇐ THIS

    children = [B]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: A.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

end
```

Note it expects the name of the application, as in `mix.exs` file (and later in the `×××.app` file after compilation.)

Comment: `A` does not want to stop `B` and restart it. `A` wants to start `B` and supervise it as part of its supervision tree. The problem here is that when `A` tries to do that, it explodes because `B` was already started (because `B` is an umbrella app in its own right). This behavior is conflicting and I am not sure it is an architectural issue from my umbrella app, or if there is something I am missing in my solution.

Comment: After a long reflection regarding the architecture of my project I have concluded it was incorrect and needs changing. My app `B` should be a statefull library instead of an elixir application. However, since your answer would technically fix the issue, I will accept it. Thanks for taking the time to read through my post!